# iOS - Video meta data re: sound muted status

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app allows videos to be uploaded.
iOS allows the user to edit their videos (via the Photos app) and remove sound.
This doesn't actually 'remove' the sound though. When I upload a video with sound edited out it is still there on the server.

Is there any meta data I can read to pass to the server so I know when audio should/shouldn't be removed when processing the uploads?

I've tried the following but can only get location and created date:

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL: url];
NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *metadata = [asset commonMetadata];

for (AVMetadataItem *item in metadata) {
  NSString *key = item.commonKey;
  NSString *value = item.stringValue;
  if (key && value) {
    [keys addObject: key];
    [values addObject: value];
  }
}
...
```